# Equivalent of FragmentTransaction attach / detach for Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments, fragment

On Android 3.2, there are 2 new methods : attach and detach for FragmentTransaction.
However these functions are not available for Android 3.0 & 3.1.
Is there a way to bypass it ?

Tkx

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to do fragment transactions just use the well documented version for 3.0 and 3.1 APIs. You should check [add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29), [remove](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove%28android.app.Fragment%29) and [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) in the [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) class.

For practical examples check [Performing Fragment Transactions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Transactions), and read the whole [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) Framework Topic. It's one of the best resources I know.

Also, check out these tutorials: 
[The Android 3.0 Fragments API](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html) and 
[How to use the Fragment class in the Android Honeycomb SDK](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2448-how-to-use-the-fragment-class-in-the-android-honeycomb-sdk-preview/).

Anyway, here is a code clipping:

```
Fragment f = new TestFragment();

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// Replaces an existing fragment with the newly created one
ft.replace(R.id.the_frag, f);
// Any transition you prefer
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
// Add it to the stack so the transition will be remembered and could be reversed
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

If you just want to [detach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#detach%28android.app.Fragment%29) or [attach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#attach%28android.app.Fragment%29) a fragment this can be done with add and remove mentioned above and make sure to inflate it's content view when you add it.